# How to store your own key-value pairs in Redis using PhpRedis with D7 Redis module

Tags: caching

We have the D7 Redis module installed, which is being used as the cache mechanism for D7 caching. That module uses PhpRedis as the underlying library.

I would like to use that same Redis instance to cache a large amount of non-Drupal data that is retrieved from an external API, then will be rendered on a specific Drupal page. I'm wondering how I can get ahold of the Redis object instance that Drupal is already using, so I can use PhpRedis functions like $redis->set(key,value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once configured/initialized, the module has a wrapper class/interface `Redis_Client`
 that contains the library object. It can be retrieved with the `getClient()` method:

`$redis = Redis_Client::getClient()`

Comment: Thanks, that works. I was attempting to use new Redis() but that doesn't connect to the existing Redis data store.